# write down the expression for $\sin (15°)$ using the double angle formula.

Tags: trigonometry

show that $\sin 15^\circ=\frac {\sqrt3 -1}{2\sqrt2}$ using $\cos2A=1-2\sin^2A$
However I got $\sin 15^\circ= \sqrt{\frac {2-\sqrt 3}{4}}$ instead.

Comment: What did you do to get that so we can follow you until your error to help you better?

Comment: Give us a little more information please. How did you come up with that result?

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your question fairly heavily, please check to make sure I didn't introduce any errors.

Comment: The 4 should have a square root as well... which I see now would simplify to 2.

Answer (score 6):

Your form, $\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt3}{4}}$, is already close:

$$\begin{align*}
\sin15^\circ &=\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt3}{4}}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{4-2\sqrt3}{8}}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{1-2\sqrt3+3}{8}}\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{(1-\sqrt3)^2}{8}}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt3 -1 }{2\sqrt2}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: could you please explain how 1-sqrt3 became sqrt3-1 ?

Comment: $\sin 15^\circ$ is positive, so the positive square root of $\frac{(1-\sqrt3)^2}8$ is taken: $\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2\sqrt2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$cos(2A)$ = $1 - 2Sin^2(A)$

$\Rightarrow$ $cos(30)$ = $1 - 2Sin^2(15)$

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ = $1 - 2Sin^2(15)$

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ - 1 = $-2Sin^2(15)$

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{\sqrt3 - 2}{2}$   = $-2Sin^2(15)$

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{\sqrt3 - 2}{4}$   = $-Sin^2(15)$

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt3}}{2}$   = $Sin(15)$

$\Rightarrow$ $\sqrt{\frac{4 - 2\sqrt3}{8}}$   = $Sin(15)$

$\Rightarrow$ $\sqrt{\frac{(\sqrt3 - 1)^2}{8}}$   = $Sin(15)$

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{(\sqrt3 - 1)}{2\sqrt2}$   = $Sin(15)$

$\Rightarrow$ $\frac{(\sqrt3 - 1)}{2\sqrt2}$   = $Sin(15)$

Comment: Although your answer is right.

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt3-2}{4}$ is negative.

Comment: @peterwhy sorry missed that - sign.

Comment: What happened from line 6 to 7? $\sqrt {-x^2} \neq -x$

Comment: @KoA seriously ashamed of myself. damn such a stupid mistake.